# example code pyhton printing card in printer evolis primacy

Tags: python

I'm working on a card printer, where some text will be printed on front page. The printer sdk lacks code samples for this kind of operation. Therefore, i'm asking if somebody has (python) code examples, on how to write/draw text string on the card.

the printer is a evolis primacy.